# How to copy from an array to a Vector256 and vice versa based on the array index?

Tags: c#, .net, simd, avx2

Supposedly I have either an `int[]` array or `Vector256<int>`s. How can I copy the values from one to another using an array index?

At the moment I have to iterate over the array indices and copy the values one by one:

```cs
int[] input = ...; // length divisible by Vector256<int>.Count
int[] output = new int[intput.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i += Vector256<int>.Count)
{
    Vector256<int> v = Vector256.Create(
                array[i], array[i + 1], array[i + 2], array[i + 3],
                array[i + 4], array[i + 5], array[i + 6], array[i + 7]);

    Vector256<int> v2 = DoSomeWork(v);

    for (int j = 0; j < Vector256<int>.Count; ++j)
    {
        output[i + j] = v2.GetElement(i + j);
    }
}
```

In Java SDK 16, there are functions that can do exactly what I need. Is there any similar function in C#?

```java
int[] input = ...;
int[] output = new int[values.length];

for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i += IntVector.SPECIES_256.length()) {
    IntVector v = IntVector.fromArray(IntVector.SPECIES_256, input, i);
    IntVector v2 = DoSomeWork(v);
    v2.intoArray(output, i);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Vector` from `System.Numerics`. Something like this:

```
var vector = new Vector<int>(new Span<int>(ints, i, 8));
Vector256<int> v = vector.AsVector256();
......
v2.AsVector().CopyTo(output, i);
```

Also you can try straightly use `System.Numerics.Vector` for your computations.

Also can use [`unsafe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/unsafe) with [`Avx.LoadVector256`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.intrinsics.x86.avx.loadvector256?view=net-5.0) and `Avx.Store` from `System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86`. Something like this:

```
fixed (int* ptr = input) 
fixed (int* ptrRes = output) 
{
    var vectorCount = Vector256<int>.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i <= input.Length - vectorCount; i += vectorCount) 
    {
        var v = Avx.LoadVector256(ptr + i);
        ....
        Avx.Store(ptrRes + i, v2);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm calling `Avx2` intrinsics, thus I think I can't use straight `Vector` and I need to convert to `Vector256` first.

Comment: May I know the reason you create a variable `vectorCount` to hold the total elements and not just directly use `Vector256<int>.Count` instead?

Comment: @b1105029 I have a small superstition that it can lead to very-very small speed improvement. Also sometimes it easier to refactor this. But you should check yourself.

Comment: @b1105029 `Vector256<int>.Count` has a constant value `8`. There's no reason to store it into the variable. As for me `const vectorCount = 8` looks better, just for code readability. Roslyn will replace it with the literal while building the app.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution.

```cs
int[] input = ...;
int[] output = new int[input.Length];
Span<Vector256<int>> inputVectors = MemoryMarshal.Cast<int, Vector256<int>>(input);
Span<Vector256<int>> outputVectors = MemoryMarshal.Cast<int, Vector256<int>>(output);
for (int i = 0; i < inputVectors.Length; i++)
    outputVectors[i] = DoSomeWork(inputVectors[i]);
```

The result will be automagically in the `output` array.

Unsafe version

```cs
int[] input = ...;
int[] output = new int[input.Length];
fixed (int* inPtr = input, outPtr = output)
{
    Vector256<int>* src = (Vector256<int>*)inPtr;
    Vector256<int>* dst = (Vector256<int>*)outPtr;
    Vector256<int>* srcEnd = src + (input.Length >> 3);
    while (src < srcEnd)
    {
        *dst = DoSomeWork(*src);
        src++;
        dst++;
    }
}
```

All 3 solutions: unsafe from the accepted answer, and both above ones have nearly the same performance.